# Is the total cost of Sovaldi, the $1,000 pill, comparable to conventional long-term treatment?

Tags: medical-science

The relatively new drug for Hepatitis C, Sovaldi, has caused a rather large controversy about the appropriate price for medication. [This NY Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/08/03/upshot/is-a-1000-pill-really-too-much.html?rref=upshot) is one example of the controversy, citing the cost at $1,000 a pill, and $84,000 for a complete treatment.

I'm not asking about what price is appropriate, this is a much more complicated debate and entirely off-topic here. But I am interested in putting the price in context, and the official statement from Gilead paints a rather different picture than most of the articles in the press I read. They state in their [policy position](http://www.gilead.com/~/media/Files/pdfs/Policy-Perspectives/Patient-Access-to-SOF-for-HCV-4-28-14.pdf):

> Sovaldi was priced such that the total regimen cost is comparable to the previous standard of care regimen for genotype 1 patients with hepatitis C.

Is that statement accurate? Is the cost for a complete treatment with Sovaldi comparable to the cost of the existing treatments for Hepatitis C?

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Dartmouth Medical School](http://www.epidemic.org/thefacts/theepidemic/USHealthCareCosts/):

> With the cost per liver transplantation in the range of $280,000 for
>   one year, liver transplantation for hepatitis C alone reaches a cost
>   of nearly $300 million per year.
>
> Moreover, the average lifetime cost for hepatitis C, in the absence of
>   liver transplant, has been estimated to be about $100,000 for
>   individual patients.

[According to the NIH](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3763475/) (which does not mention liver transplants specifically):

> The lifetime cost of an individual infected with HCV in 2011 was estimated at $64,490. However, this cost is significantly higher among individuals with a longer life expectancy.

The big difference seems to be that Sovaldi is a *cure* and has the entire cost occur within a treatment period of 12 or 24 weeks, whereas existing treatments consisted of "managing" the disease and spread out the cost over years or decades.